# Gui simulation for smart home application

Tags: user-interface

im looking for suggestion in which GUI tool is most appropriate for me to use in implementing my study. im using java language. i would like the graphics to simulate a house in which graphical changes apply without user inputs from mouse or keyboards. my user input is in the form of sms. thanks in advance guys. im hoping to animate it or simulate a smart home through the conditions i had set in my program. thnaks!

Comment: The question is very unclear. If you're input is SMS, do you just need a graphical *display* of something (what?)? That would require a GUI as such (i.e. no need to take input from the mouse or the keyboard). Or do you need an interface to simulate the sms system for now?

Comment: yup, the conditions i had set will depend on the sms that the user will send to the system. the system will read the sms and will decide if it will turn on or off a certain appliance. yups i need an interface or a graphic simulation for the system. for example there will be a house, if the system receives a certain sms, a certain part of the house will light up. i dont know what tool i will use to achieve this. sorry for the unclear question dmckee, i hope you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions is very underspecified. I will assume that you are at the early stages of producing a hand-rolled home automation programs, you probably need:

1. an environment to let you test the core logic of the system (i.e. "If the system is in state X and I issue command Y, what does it actually do, and will I lose the contents of my freezer?")
2. an environment to let you test the SMS communications module
3. you may need a demo mode to show prospecitve customers what it does (this is my best guess at what is being requested here)

Now (3) could fill in for (1), but is a lot more programming effort, so from the start you probably want a simple text interface to do (1).

In general, you almost certainly want a modular system: a core logic system supported by at least two input models (SMS and keyboard), three output models (text debug, graphical demo, and control-line/wireless signals for the actual hardware), and various ancillary stuff (configuration reading, saved state handling). Come to think of it, since you probably need a way to probe the current state of the system, you should make the saved state and condition probe code share a single framework as well.

Comment: thanks dmckee. number 3 is actually my main concern right now as of the core logic of the system is already done. can give me any suggestions foe which tool i will use for my graphic demo for perspective customers?
im using java in developing this system. thanks in advance. by the way, the system will not require any keyboard input from the user. im still a student and im developing this for my project. thanks a bunch, i really hope you could help me.

Comment: by the way the main purpose of the system is to only turn on and turn off appliances. thanks.

Comment: So, if you have the core system written already, then you have chosen an implementation language? Knowing which one you are using would help with choosing GUI framework.